# wrapping a response not render jsp content

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlet-filters

I have a custom filter that implements Filter and I wrap the response with a ContentCachingResponseWrapper like this

```
HttpServletResponse responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
```

after that I open localhost and I see nothing, only white screen.

```
<html>
<head><head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

If I comment the ContentCachingResponseWrapper and use the response without wrapping it

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

then my jsp page is rendered correctly.

Can anyone explain what's happening?

Comment: user7294900, Thank you! I've added this to my interceptor but I forgot to add this to my filter

Answer (score 0):

After adding `((ContentCachingResponseWrapper) responseWrapper).copyBodyToResponse();` after `chain.doFilter(requestToCache, responseWrapper);` problem was solved